# Broad Scrapy Crawl: sgmlLinkextractor rule does not work

Tags: scrapy

I've spent a lot of time playing around and using google but I could not solve my problem. I am new to Scrapy and I hope you can help me.

Part of the spider that works: I define my start_requests urls out of a MySQL Datbase. With the 'parse_item' statement I write the response into seperate files. Both of these steps work fine.

My Problem: Additionally I want to follow every url which contains '.ch' and - as I do for the start_requests - send them to the 'parse_item' method. I therefore defined a rule with a sgmlLinkExtractor and the 'parse_item' method as the callback. This does not work. After completion, I only have the files for the urls defined in 'start_requests'. I don't get any error messages.

Here is my code:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
import mysql.connector
from scrapy.http import Request

class FirstSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'firstspider'
start_urls = []

def start_requests(self):
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password = 'root', host= 'localhost', database = 'Eistee')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    query = ("SELECT Domain, CompanyName FROM Crawlbydomain LIMIT 300, 100")

    cursor.execute(query)

    results = cursor.fetchall()

    for result in results:
        urlrequest = 'http://'+result[0]
        yield Request(urlrequest, callback = self.parse_item )

rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('.ch', )), callback='parse_item', follow= True),)

def parse_item(self, response):

    filename = response.url.translate(None, './')
    open(filename, 'wb').write(response.body)
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make `CrawlSpider` do its "magic" you need the requests to go through `CrawlSpider`'s `parse()` callback.

So in `start_requests()` your Requests must use `callback=self.parse` (or not set the `callback` argument)

If you also want the start Requests to go through `parse_item` you need to set a `parse_start_url` attribute in your spider set to `parse_item`.

So you need to have something like:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
import mysql.connector
from scrapy.http import Request

class FirstSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'firstspider'

    def start_requests(self):
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password = 'root', host= 'localhost', database = 'Eistee')
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        query = ("SELECT Domain, CompanyName FROM Crawlbydomain LIMIT 300, 100")

        cursor.execute(query)

        results = cursor.fetchall()

        for result in results:
            urlrequest = 'http://'+result[0]
            yield Request(urlrequest)

    rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('.ch', )), callback='parse_item', follow= True),)

    def parse_item(self, response):

        filename = response.url.translate(None, './')
        open(filename, 'wb').write(response.body)

    parse_start_url = parse_item
```

Comment: To send the start requests to the parse_item function too, I used this method: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scrapy-users/lAYpjTAP46Q